# query error duplicate column id sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Why this query return with error of duplicate id? I'm using php

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products  as prd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM product_aliases) AS product_aliases
    ON product_aliases.product_id = prd.id 
    AND product_aliases.alias = '$alias'

    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM product_images as prdim
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  product_image_votes as prdimvt 
            ON prdimvt.product_image_id = prdim.id) AS productimages 
    ON productimages.product_id = prd.id 
WHERE prd.id = $id
```

ERROR:

> Database Error Error: SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060
>   Duplicate column name 'id' SQL Query: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products
>   as prd LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM product_aliases) AS
>   product_aliases ON product_aliases.product_id = prd.id AND
>   product_aliases.alias = 'Pringles The Original' LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM product_images as prdim LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   product_image_votes as prdimvt ON prdimvt.product_image_id = prdim.id)
>   AS productimages ON productimages.product_id = prd.id WHERE prd.id = 1

Comment: I suspect this has to do with the sub select join. I think this query can be written without the sub selects.

Comment: I need sub query because I have to put limit after and because I want to use distinct in the select inside @datasage

Comment: Distinct would only reduce duplicates, are there actually duplicates in those tables?

Comment: yes it can be duplicates @datasage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 tables in your query and it is possible at least 2 of them have the same column `id`. Using `*` in your select would select all columns in these three tables selecting `id` multiple times

You could solve this by specifying the columns using the alias

```
SELECT DISTINCT prd.id, prd.Name FROM products  as prd
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM product_aliases) AS product_aliases
ON product_aliases.product_id = prd.id 
AND product_aliases.alias = '$alias'
... rest of your query here
```

You could also do

```
SELECT DISTINCT prd.* FROM products  as prd
```

if you don't want to list them one by one

Comment: In every select I have to put name_table.* and now no return error. Thanks